# "function not defined" in firebug

Tags: php, javascript

I am using an external javascript file to call a function and it will not. i get function not defined in firebug too.
the name of the external js file is getpic.js
in the html, i put this in the header:

```
<script src="getpic.js"  type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

php:

```
echo "<button id='sldkfj' onclick='hg();'>sdlkfj</button>";
```

js:

```
function hg()
{
alert("hello")

}
```

the file system is basically in one folder for wamp
this is all of getpic.js

```
function hg()
{
alert("hello")

}
```

for the php part

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="getpic.js"  type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>
<body> 

   <?php
echo "<button id='sldkfj' onclick='hg();'>sdlkfj</button>";

?>
```

EDIT-----
i also keep getting this in firebug:

```
Reload the page to get source for: http://localhost/iframe/getpic.js
```

Thanks

Comment: need to see where hg is declared

Comment: can you give us all of getpic.js?

Comment: Is getpic.js actually being loaded?

Comment: Can you post your file structure, please?

Comment: Looking at the network tab in firefox, are all assets successfully loaded?

Comment: Your html file and js file need to be in the same folder. In fact, you even should be able to access the js file using your browser, the same way you access your html file.

Answer (score 2):

Edit:
add the code segment to the html page as a

```
    <script  type="text/javascript">
    function hg()
    {
       alert("hello");
    }
    </script>
```

if still it doesnt work there should be something wrong with the browser.
(disabled java script) try a different browser

if it works,
obviously there's an error in linking the file.
on firebug go to the script panel and see whether it is loaded or not. (you can also use net panel as well)
try linking

```
<script src="/getpic.js"  type="text/javascript">
```

if you are at the localhost(www) directory or the absolute path

```
<script src="/mytest/getpic.js"  type="text/javascript">
```

---

add ; at the end of the alert() command

```
 function hg()
 {
  alert("hello");
 }
```

Comment: as others suggest can you give us the js file?

Comment: what do you mean?  i put all that was in the js file in my question. there is only one function.

Comment: A semicolon won't make a difference.

Answer (score -2):

Try taking the script tag out of the head element and put it in the body. I've had this problem before and that's what fixed it for me.

Comment: Actually, this information is completely wrong. Through and through.